# Get duplicate CNContacts from ContactStore?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, cncontact

I'm trying to get duplicate `CNContacts` in **iOS 9 Contacts Framework** and I quite can't find a good solution.

I have tried to get them and loop trough but it's kinda slow and on older devices it will be slower..

This is the **best** I have succeeded on iPhone 6(500 contacts with 134 duplicates):

```
        func fetchDuplicateContacts(){

        self.arr_duplicateContacts.removeAll();
        NSLog("Start fetch duplicate", "")
        for (var i: Int = 0; i < self.arr_allContacts.count; i++){
            let contact1 = self.arr_allContacts[i]
            for (var j: Int = ++i; j < self.arr_allContacts.count; j++){
                let contact2 = self.arr_allContacts[j]
                if(contact1 != contact2){
                    if CNContactFormatter.stringFromContact(contact1, style: .FullName) == CNContactFormatter.stringFromContact(contact2, style: .FullName){
                        print("Move on cuz duplicate: \(CNContactFormatter.stringFromContact(contact1, style: .FullName))")
                        self.arr_duplicateContacts.append(contact2)
                        i = j;

//                        break; <- Commented because it can be 2-3-4 duplicate contacts
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        NSLog("End fetch duplicate", "")
        self.mytable.reloadData()
    }
```

The NSLogs shows me:

> 2015-11-30 22:18:03.528 Coxxxxx[5312:1581719] Start fetch duplicate
>
> 2015-11-30 22:18:05.812 Conxxx[5312:1581719] End fetch duplicate

**Is there an `Contacts Framework API` I'm not aware of it to get duplicates? Or how can I improve it to go faster?**

Comment: Even the best solutions for getting duplicates will more than likely still miss some duplicates. There's no solution to check what a duplicate is because there's so much information that a contact can hold that you would have to compare all fields and then accept a standard of acceptable "percentage match" error that you are comfortable with. Nothing in IOS framework can do this for you, it's all just a matter of how much error can you handle and how correct you want to try to be.

Comment: Hey @Larcerax. Thanks for reply. I was referring in terms of performance. For the begining I have only compared name but I will also compare other properties but it is slow and it will will get slower and that's why I take my question here to see if there is a better way to do this...

Comment: I see what you are saying. The only speed performance boost that may work, but probably not that much and it's going to complicate things due to "no indexing" is to use NSSets and NSMutableSets instead of using arrays. but this won't do much for you more than likely unless you are hitting 10s of thousands of values in the set. Sorry about that, I konw myself that the contacts book stuff is slow for whatever reason.

Comment: I get contacts pretty fast like 0.2 seconds which is ok and I keep them cached for better performance, updating them on CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification and I guess I will do this in background at appstart and cache them if no other way to do that..

Comment: You could also, MAYBE, just pull down contacts whenever you need an update and then store them server side to pull them from the server faster, for example, I know facebook and instagram does this, but this gets into territory that Apple doesnt like very much.

Comment: I'm trying to keep it offline as much as I will can.. Thanks anyway